# The scroll en fancy box does not work on iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

When I open the page on iPhone or Ipad the scroll of the fancybox does not work. On the other hand, is working in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari (pc and mac) and Android (phone or tablet).

[This](http://www.kablyfertilidad.com/hemos2.html) is the page push the bottom "saber mas"

Thanks

Comment: You should make a separate version for mobile devices anyways, that way of displaying stuff on a mobile device sucks.

Comment: I have only problem with iPhone or iPad the other device work fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'll work if you use two fingers, or in iOS5 you can do:

```
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Lightboxes aren't a very pleasant experience for mobile users, though.

Comment: In your CSS file, for the particular element you want it to apply to

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this was my solution, I added this to my css

```
#fancybox-inner{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: Fancybox-inner has now become a class, not an ID.